# Convert audio/video stream to mp4 on-the-fly

Tags: android, opengl-es, mp4, android-mediacodec

I have an audio and video stream and would like to generate an mp4. However, all the samples I've seen tend to generate an mp4 when it has the entire stream. What I want to accomplish is to encode the stream to mp4 while receiving the audio/video stream from the web.

It isn't clear whether an mp4 can be created on-the-fly or needs to wait until the final input data has been received. I believe that this has to be possible because when you record a video on your device using the camera, as soon as you stop recording, the video is already available. This means that it was encoding it on-the-fly. So it really shouldn't matter whether the frames come from the camera or from a video stream over the web. Or am I possibly missing something?

Without knowing how mp4 is actually generated, I'm guessing that even if the encoder receives a few seconds of frames and audio, it still can generate that portion of the mp4 and save it to disk. At any point in time, my app should be able to stop the streaming and the encoder just saves the final portion of the stream. What would be nice is that if the app were to crash during encoding, that at least the part that was encoded still gets saved to disk as a valid mp4. Not sure if that is even possible.

Ultimately I would like to do this using the MediaCodec, OpenGL ES and a Surface.